# PHPDoc on OSX via PEAR

Tags: pear, phpdoc

I'm running OS 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion).

I did a fresh install of PEAR just as this blog states:

http://clickontyler.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pear-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

So I set `include_path` in my `php.ini` file to `/usr/local/share/pear`. Then I installed apigen via pear and everything works fine. I then wanted to install phpdoc, but after I installed it, I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/usr/lib/php/pear/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpdoc on line 33
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/usr/lib/php/pear/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /usr/bin/phpdoc on line 33
```

After searching on SO, I found this QA:
[PhpDocumentor installed via PEAR on OSX not working - missing files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871038/phpdocumentor-installed-via-pear-on-osx-not-working-missing-files/872362#872362)

So, when I do `pear config-show` it shows that my `php_dir` is set to `/usr/local/share/pear` which is exactly what is set in my php.ini

However, it seems that phpdoc is trying to use `/usr/lib/php/pear` as the directory still.

**The `/usr/lib/php/pear` folder doesn't exist!** So, if I change my pear configs to this folder, it will break my other pear-installed commands.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: please convert your solution into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just about to give up when I found a solution.

OS X was using PHP 5.3, so I manually updated it to 5.4.10.

Then, I reinstalled `PEAR`, then reinstalled `apigen` then reinstalled `phpdoc` and it all worked fine.

To update PHP on my system, I followed the following:
http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/